# What are some unique opportunities and lodging in Siwa Oasis, Egypt?

Tags: egypt, deserts

I will be traveling to [Siwa Oasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siwa_Oasis) sometime near the end of 2011. I was wondering if anyone has any experience with great/unique places to stay, or potentially an overnight trip into the desert. Looking for names of places or providers of that type of service.

Also open to other exciting/unique opportunities in this area of travel.

Comment: Ooh, jealous, one of two places in Egypt that I didn't get to go to while I was there that I really want to see one day :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I haven't been myself, I've done some research so figured I may as well share.

For tours and excursions:

[The Siwa Guide](http://www.siwaguide.com) - desert safaris, and they describe a sea of sand stretching as far as the eye can see. They have half day, full day and custom trips - which could include camel safaris, or camping under the stars.

[Abu-Zahra Bedouin Safaris](http://www.bedouinsafari.org/Web/Programs.htm)  - promote themselves as more environmentally-focused tourism.

As for accommodation, you haven't really specified budget, medium or high:

For budget - [Palm Trees Hotel](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g303857-d646930-Reviews-Palm_Trees_Hotel-Siwa.html) sounds the most fun and scenic, with "nice garden with trees and fire pit, where the staff will sit at night with guests. Roof terrace with a view of the oasis and Shali" (review on Wikitravel)

For medium - [Shali Lodge](http://www.epoquehotels.com/h.php/siwah-oasis-hotels/boutique-hotel/h/shalilodgehotel/l/en) - sounds pretty smart for good value, and has some exotic local foods on the menu - date omelet, lamb casserole or vegetarian tajin, each flavored with fresh herbs of the oasis.

For deluxe - two amazing and different options - the [Adrere Amellal: Desert Ecolodge](http://www.adrereamellal.net/index2.html) - with no electricity, the rooms are softly lit with a dozen beeswax candles, and around the corner, the Tamazigh, a smaller hotel, with a spring-fed pool and some rooms made entirely of salt!